# Polygons not showing outlines in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, outline

I work in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1. I imported a project (.mxd) from ArcMap 10.8.1.
There are two map frames in a layout view. One is placed onto another. There are polygons in the second map frame that I am unable to display outline symbology.

Fill color, dashed outline, everything works fine. Just when I want just a simple stroke full outline, it's not appearing.

It works with no problems in ArcMap. Also the outlines work normally in the first map frame.

Does anyone know what is the cause?

[image]

Here's a working picture from ArcMap
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Map Frames rather than Data Frames?  What do you mean by nested?  I think a picture would be enlightening.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. Nested was just my expression for putting one Data Frame onto another.

Comment: If you haven't you might try to repeat the import and see if it works the second time as expected.  If it doesn't you might try removing the layer and saving the project.  Then reopening it and adding the layer back in and then setting the symbology.  Sometimes conversions fail and there's no obvious reason why,

Comment: No, sir. It didn't help. I added new feature layer and still it doesn't display outlines, only fills. I've never seen something like this before.

Comment: I just created a whole new polygon feature class, created a new Map Frame inside the existing one and guess what? It has only fill colour, no outline. Like it's invisible. Isn't there a default setting for something like this?